# Sql Server Flatten Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks similar to this

```
RowNumber   Value                     colIdx
1           A                         1
1           Shimano Dura-Ace          2     
2           B                         1
2           SRAM eTap                 2
3           C                         1
3           Campagnolo Super Record   2
```

I want to flatten rows, and so far I have come up with the following

```
SELECT Rownumber,
       stuff(
               (SELECT DISTINCT ': ' + cast(value AS varchar(MAX))
                FROM groupsets t2
                WHERE t2.Rownumber = t1.Rownumber
                  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM groupsets t1
GROUP BY Rownumber
ORDER BY Rownumber
```

However, the following is produced - I want for the single character to always prefix the value.

```
RowNumber   Value
1           A: Shimano Dura-Ace
2           B: SRAM eTap
3           Campagnolo Super Record: D
```

I have created a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64fa7/2). I'm not sure how to order by `colIdx` without needing to expose it?

The expected output is:

```
RowNumber   Value
1           A: Shimano Dura-Ace
2           B: SRAM eTap
3           D: Campagnolo Super Record
```

Comment: Perhaps add an `ORDER BY` to your subquery. I'd probably suggest `LEN([value])`.

Comment: @Larnu Adding an orderby to the subquery disrupts the output (it will be outputted as XML)

Comment: Then add a `CONVERT(varchar(MAX),...`.

Comment: Please see my answer if you don't like using stuff/xml ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasets in SQL Server are **never** guaranteed to be returned in any specific order without using an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you need to guarantee that the single character will be returned first, you'll need to use an `ORDER BY`. For example:

```
SELECT Rownumber,
       STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(MAX),(SELECT DISTINCT ': ' + [value] --Is the DISTINCT required here?
                                                                  --Also, the CAST is not required, that goes on the outside of the SELECt, as you can see
                                   FROM groupsets t2
                                   WHERE t2.Rownumber = t1.Rownumber
                                   ORDER BY LEN([value]) ASC
                                   FOR XML PATH(''))),1,1,'')
FROM groupsets t1
GROUP BY Rownumber
ORDER BY Rownumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

While digging a bit I saw some new feature in SQL Server 2017 (and azure). Here's a query that will work using a CTE + **STRING_AGG** (New feature).

```
WITH groupsetsOrdered AS
(
    SELECT top 100000 rownumber, [value], [colIdx]
    FROM groupsets
    ORDER BY rownumber, colidx 
)
select rownumber as [RowNumber], string_agg([value], ': ') as [Value]
from groupsetsOrdered
group by rownumber
order by rownumber
```

**Dataset like:**

```
CREATE TABLE groupsets
    ([Rownumber] varchar(1), [Value] varchar(max), [colidx] int)
;

INSERT INTO groupsets
    ([Rownumber], [Value], [colidx])
VALUES
    ('1', 'A',1),
    ('1', 'Shimano Dura-Ace',2),
    ('2', 'SRAM eTap',2),
    ('2', 'B',1),
    ('3', 'D',1),
    ('3', 'Campagnolo Super Record',2)
;
```

**Result:**

```
rownumber   Value
1   A: Shimano Dura-Ace
2   B: SRAM eTap
3   D: Campagnolo Super Record
```

(Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/707ec/9/0)